# AutoIt: What test environments or live interpreters available to test scripts?

Tags: debugging, interpreter, autoit, test-environments

Something like [PyScripter](http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/)'s Python Interpreter, so I can type and run commands immediately (pictured towards the bottom of the following screen shot).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [Au3Int (Interpreter for AutoIt)](http://code.google.com/p/au3int/) which is very limited in what it can do, but allows you to execute lines of code. The beta version can work with function calls and multi-line statements, but it's buggy and not great.

Unfortunately, AutoIt was not designed with this in mind, so you are going to struggle.

Answer (score 3):

This is the only debugger for AutoIt that even remotely does what you want to: http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/21834-graphical-autoit-debugger/